# Unit test case polling service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.timeInterval = interval(30000).pipe(startWith(0), switchMap(() => this.deviceService.getDeviceSession())
    ).subscribe((success: any) => {
      this.rowData = success;
      console.log(this.rowData)
      
    }, (error: any) => {
      this.rowData = [];
      if (error.error && error.error.status !== 401) {
        this.toastService.error('Error in loading data');
      }
    }
    
Test Case    

it('should start checking for data after every interval', (done) => {
const dataService = TestBed.get(DeviceService);
// Mock the getStatus function
spyOn(dataService, 'getDeviceSession').and.returnValue(Observable.create().pipe(map(() => 'woo')));
// Should not be initialised yet
expect(component.rowData).toBeUndefined();

setTimeout(()=> {
      expect(component.rowData).toBe('woo');
      done();
},30000);
```

});

I am writing this unit test case to check this polling implementation, which is fetching data(array of objects) from service and updating it in the Dom. But the test case is getting failed. I am not sure where i am going wrong.
Getting error rowData.forEach is not a function. Please help how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Use Jasmin's beforeEach\before to initiate some data before it() instead of doing it in ngOnInit.

https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global

So if im getting right what youre doing is, you initiate the rowData attribute in the ngOnInit life cycle hook. but it's not yet available inside of your it() function.

If you want to run some code and initiate data before you are runing your tests you should use the beforeEach() function and only then it()

check the image bellow:
https://miro.medium.com/max/4800/1*CklcdftSg9EFGsU20ZwdJg.png

A nice guide for doing unit tests with Angular and Jasmine:
https://medium.com/swlh/angular-unit-testing-jasmine-karma-step-by-step-e3376d110ab4

Comment: I dont get it. could you explain more?